# How to use a for loop to ignore every non-alphabetic character in a string and add to a new string? Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to ignore every non-alphabetic character in a string and add the alphabetic string to a new string so it can be checked if it is a palindrome regardless of case.

So far I have

```
new_str = ''
for ch in s:
    ch = ch.lower
    if s.isalpha():
        s = s + new_str

return s == is_palindrome
```

I am calling is_palindrome prom a previous function which checks if a lowercase word is a palindrome.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `string.ascii_letters` --  `''.join(char for char in s if char in string.ascii_letters).lower()` this will give you a lower-cased version of a string with only characters that are ascii_letters.

Comment: You're not calling `is_palindrome()` at all, in fact -- the last line checks whether the `s` (a string) is equal to `is_palindrome` (a function)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Question has been edited, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code. Let’s go through them one by one:

1. `ch = ch.lower`

   In order to call a function or a method, you need to use parentheses `()` after the function name to tell Python to actually call that function/method. The way you are doing it here, you will just assign a *reference to the **function*** to `ch`. So `ch` won’t be a character afterwards. What you want to do is use `ch = ch.lower()`.
2. `if s.isalpha():`

   This check is generally okay, however `s` is probably not what you mean there. `s` is the full string, while `ch` is the current *character* in the iteration. You probably meant `if ch.isalpha()` here.
3. `s = s + new_str`

   Again, `s` is the full string which characters you are iterating through. You probably did not mean to append something to `s` here. You probably want to collect some result in a different variable.

   Speaking of result, `new_str` is initialized to the empty string `''` and is never modified, so you are appending an empty string to the string `s` (which will not do anything).

   What you *probably* meant to do is modify `new_str`, and append the *character* if the earlier condition was true: `new_str = new_str + ch`
4. `return s == is_palindrome`

   Same as before, in order to call a function, you need to use parentheses. Otherwise you would be comparing the string `s` with the `is_palindrome` function here (which is unlikely to ever be true).

   Furthermore, `s` is the input string (which you accidentally modified throughout the loop?). You probably meant to check `new_str` here.

   And finally, `is_palindrome` probably takes a string as an input and returns whether or not that string is a palindrome. So you wouldn’t want to compare its result against the string anyway.

The full code would probably look like this after the fixes:

```
new_str = ''
for ch in s:
    ch = ch.lower()
    if ch.isalpha():
        new_str = new_str + ch

return is_palindrome(new_str)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to go through it step by step! Your explanation is great

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to drop all of the non-alphas from your string:

```
s = 'A man, a plan, a canal: Panama!'
scrunched_s = ''.join(ch.lower() for ch in s if ch.isalpha())
reversed_s = ''.join(ch.lower() for ch in s[::-1] if ch.isalpha())
print s
print scrunched_s
print reversed_s
print scrunched_s == reversed_s
```

Here is another:

```
scrunched_s = map(str.lower, filter(str.isalpha, s))
reversed_s = map(str.lower, filter(str.isalpha, reversed(s)))
print scrunched_s == reversed_s
```

Comment: Why not use the built-in `reversed` function on `scrunched_s`?

Comment: @sytech - Mostly clarity. If I am creating a generator expression or list comprehension then I use indexing operations. If I am using functional notation, then I use `reversed`, as in my second example.

Comment: I really think the second example is a Python anti-pattern. As for the second, it's much clearer to just write `reversed_s = scunched_s[::-1]`